# Free web hosting with Tomcat?

Tags: apache, tomcat, web-hosting

I have a `.war` file that needs to be deployed in a public ip in order to work. Do you know a free web host that I could try to deploy it? I know dozens solutions with Apache, PHP , MySQL but never really heard anything about Tomcat.

Any ideas?

Comment: Other than Tomcat, do you have other requirements? e.g. RDBMS
You could look at Google's App Engine, but they intend to start charging if you want to use SQL. https://developers.google.com/appengine/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simplest answer, even if this requires a bit of work, AWS.

1. Create a free AWS account.
2. Fire up EC2 instance in free tier
3. Login to EC2 instance(your own server)
4. Download tomcat via wget
5. Assign public IP to that instance and open port 8080 or whatever you assign
6. Deploy and enjoy!

Comment: You can also deploy on OpenShift which provides free tomcat 6 and tomcat 7 hosting https://www.openshift.com/blogs/run-your-java-tomcat-application-for-free-on-openshifts-paas